# Preg replace with words from an array

Tags: php, regex

I have an array of words that have to be replaced from a string, let's call it `$my_replacements`.  I also have a string, let's call it `$my_string`, that can contain some of those values in.

Right now I have this:

```
foreach ($my_replacements as $replacement) {
    $replaced_value = preg_replace("/(^|[\n\r\f\t \.\,])" . $replacement . "([\n\r\f\t \.\,]|$)/iu", '', $my_string);
    if($replaced_value !== $my_string) {
       break;
    }
}
```

And this was good if at the first replacement I wanted to exit the foreach.  However, if the strings contains one or more of those values to be replaced it won't work.  How can I use preg_replace to find those words, and replace them all?  And it's important that I know if any replacements have been done.

Comment: Did you try preg_replace_all or adding the /g switch?

Comment: I guess there is no preg_replace_all...

Comment: Is not about finding all the ocurrences of a particular word, but finding all words.

Comment: preg_replace is always all. there is no global flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use indexed arrays with `preg_replace()`.

```
<?php
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '/fox/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = 'slow';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
$replacements[2] = 'bear';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
The slow black bear jumped over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: The replacement have to be always the same. My confusion is how would I use all the values in my array to form an array of patterns with this format: "/(^|[\n\r\f\t \.\,])" . $replacement . "([\n\r\f\t \.\,]|$)/iu"

Comment: @HommerSmith I suppose `array_map("somefunc", $my_replacements)` with `function somefunc($r) { return "/(^|[\n\r\f\t \.\,])" . $replacement . "([\n\r\f\t \.\,]|$)/iu"; }` can do it

Answer (score 2):

```
$word              = array("test","test1");
$search_string     = "(".implode("|",$word).")";
$value             = preg_replace("/$search_string\s+\S+)/i","$1",$text);
```

Try this..